# Tridion 2011 in 64bit App Pool

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Is it possible to run SDL Tridon 2011 SP1 HR1 in an x64 Classic pipeline Application Pool under IIS 7.5.

The reason for the request is my SSO provider includes an ISAPI filter that must run in an x64 pool, in classic mode, due to increased security in IIS 7.5.

Current error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4ED977D7-A765-11D5-8071-00B0D0B98279} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: wouldn't you explicitly need to change all the configs to support classic mode if it's currently set up as an integrated configuration? what's the minimum IIS version for 2011?

Comment: web.configs have sections for both integrated and classic modes and I am running recommended OS, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Comment: It works in classic 32bit pool, but SSO filter cannot run under 32bit pool.

Comment: Chris, did you get any further with this? Hoping to get this Q answered here on SO ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research, you **must** *'enable 32-Bit applications'* on the Tridion 2011 App_Pool.

[image: IIS 7 - enable 32-Bit applications]

I hear this will be sorted for Tridion 2013.

Comment: Chris, Would you like to post this as an answer to your question ?